# Dynamically subscribe to topics with Mosquitto bridge

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, messagebroker

I would like to know if it is possible in a standard MQTT bridge configuration with **Mosquitto** the *dynamic subscription* of topics from the MQTT clients to the remote broker.

That is, only if a client requests the subscription to a certain topic, it is **Mosquitto** who requests to the remote broker the subscription to that topic.

From what I have seen in the configuration it is possible to set it statically when starting the **Mosquitto** service but not dynamically according to the requirements of the MQTT clients who can decide at runtime to which topics they want to subscribe.

Is it possible in a **Mosquitto** bridge, a dynamic subscription scenario in which the subscription request of the clients is forwarded to the remote broker?

Comment: @romkey I have been searching about this topic in multiple sites, there is very little information about this, neither in GitHub Issues nor in StackOverflow, nor in Mosquitto's manual nor even in the bridges guides. If you have anything to contribute on this, it would be interesting.

Comment: Set up an instance of Mosquitto, bridge it to another and perform an experiment. You can easily see whether Mosquitto forwards the subscription requests or not. It would take just a few minutes.

Comment: I'm not criticizing you for not having done this. I'm saying you already have the tools to answer your question and encouraging you to experiment.

Comment: @romkey Why do you assume I haven't done that? I created this post because I found that Mosquitto does not redirect subscription messages from clients to the remote broker so I am asking if there is a way to do that.

Comment: I feel very sorry for the arrogance of this community, posting here has been my last resort but even that is no longer possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible, the broker does not support dynamically changing the bridge subscription.

It's also doing dynamic subscription forwarding won't work well in a situation where usernames/password and ACLs are implemented because the bridge connection acts as any other client connection. This means that the bridge connection can only subscribe/publish to topics allowed by the user assigned to the bridge.

Both brokers are likely to have very different sets of users and ACLs in place

Comment: I understand that it would be a matter of having an ACL on the bridge in line with that of the remote broker, but technically it would be possible to make this dynamic subscription.